# How to configure RewriteCond with sub-domain on Apache2?

Tags: apache

I'm using RewriteCond to redirect the requests made on port 80 to 443. It works at 
https://my.url.com

Here the configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =my.url.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =my.url2.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

However I would like to have https://my.url.com/vocab/arch

Where I have to specify the path /vocab/arch ?

Regards

Comment: It is unclear, what do you want to happen with that path?

Comment: @DusanBajic opening https://my.url.com I would like to have https://my.url.com/vocab/arch

Comment: Is the above config from `.htaccess` file or from apache `.conf` file?

Comment: nope, above 000-default.conf file in apache2/sites-enabled

Comment: Try adding as fifth line: `RewriteRule ^/$ /vocab/arch [R=302]`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but, it doesn't work

Comment: Actually, you need that line in your :443 virtual host configuration

Comment: Ok, I tried. I'm having the URL like https://www.myurl.net/vocab/arch. However opening the page I'm having this error "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

Comment: Well, does it exist if you type that address directly in browser address bar?

Comment: in :443 configuration I added  ```<Location /vocab/arch>
      ProxyPass          http://my.url.net:3000/
      ProxyPassReverse      http://my.url.net:3000/
    Require all granted
  </Location>```. I'm getting something however I'm loosing the css and the link to the others pages.